# highlighted searching text on WebView android 4.x

Tags: android

I have a problem with highlighted searching text on WebView android 4.x

I use

```
mWebView.findAll("Text to Search");
```

with

```
Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE); 
m.invoke(mWebView, true);
```

or

```
for (Method m : WebView.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {

                            if (m.getName().equals("setFindIsUp")) {
                                m.setAccessible(true);
                                m.invoke(mWebView, true);
                                break;
                            }
```

both of them worked great on android 2.2 but not on android 4.x

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It crashes? Not the expected result?

Comment: highlighted work only for android 2.2 when I install the app on android 4.x the highlighted disappear

Answer (score 0):

Try findallAsync() in stead of findall() for 4x versions I guess find all is deprecated for them.